# Trigger on Account object not able to find variable ChangedAcc

Tags: apex, trigger

Based on the recommendations before I have followed all the sets from 1 to 3 as mentioned in the solution provided. But it is giving me some errors or I am making some mistake. Not completely sure. My code is as follows:-

```
 trigger accountCreation on Account (before insert, before update) {
    //Store all Zip Codes in a SET
    SET<String> zipCodes = new SET<STRING>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            for(Account newAccount : Trigger.new) {
              zipCodes.add(newAccount.BillingPostalCode);  
            } 
        }
    }
    //Find changed Zip Codes
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            SET<ID> changedAccount = new SET<ID>();
            for(Account changedAcc : Trigger.new) {
                String oldZip = Trigger.oldMap.get(changedAcc.Id).BillingPostalCode;
                String newZip = changedAcc.BillingPostalCode;
                    if(newZip != oldZip) {
                    zipCodes.add(newZip);
                    changedAccount.add(changedAcc.Id);               
      
                }   
            }    
        }
     //Query for Territory__c records matching the set of Zip Codes
    //and storing the query results in a MAP
    MAP<String, Territory__c> terrMap = new MAP<String, Territory__c>();
    LIST<Territory__c> zipMatch = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID, Zip_Code__c
                                   FROM Territory__c
                                   WHERE Zip_Code__c IN:zipCodes];
    for(Territory__c terr : zipMatch) {
        terrMap.put(terr.Zip_Code__c, terr);
    }
    //Iterate over the Account again for those Accounts
    //with changed Zip Codes and look for associated
    //Territory via Zip and assign the Account's OwnerId
    //field to the value of that Territory's Owner__c field
    for(Account iterAccount : changedAcc) {
        Territory__c lookTerr = terrMap.get(iterAccount.BillingPostalCode);
        if(lookTerr != NULL) {
            lookTerr.Owner__c = iterAccount.OwnerId;
        }
    }    
 }
}
```

Comment: In the line `for(Account iterAccount : changedAcc)`, you are trying to use `changedAcc` which was declared & used in a nested FOR loop earlier. The scope of `changedAcc` is within the nested FOR loop and hence, the err.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                changedAccount.add(changedAcc.Id);
```

You will want to be adding the Account itself to a `List<Account>`, rather than its Id to a `Set<Id>`, and you'll need to declare this variable outside the loop.

```
for(Account iterAccount : changedAcc) {
    Territory__c lookTerr = terrMap.get(iterAccount.BillingPostalCode);
    if(lookTerr != NULL) {
        lookTerr.Owner__c = iterAccount.OwnerId;
    }
}
```

And then here, you would iterate over (the new variable that you changed above) `changedAccount`, not `changedAcc`, which is not in scope at this point in your trigger.

Note also that your assignment statement is *not* doing what the comment says it should be.

These are easy mistakes for a newer engineer to make, but they're also easy to fix. A practice that you can adopt for yourself is "rubber duck debugging": read through your code, slowly, and explain it out loud, as if you are addressing a rubber duck or some other inanimate prop. This can help make errors in logic clear to you.

Comment: I have updated changedAcc to ChangedAccount in the FOR loop. But still gives me the same error message. Plus could you explain as to what should I be doing when you say - Note also that your assignment statement is not doing what the comment says it should be

Comment: @vijayzutshi Read through your code carefully. What does the comment tell you you are intending to assign, and what are you actually assigning? I've updated my answer to be clearer about the variable issue.

Comment: So if I am not mistaken my assignment should be iterAccount.OwnerId = lookTerr.Owner__c. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The trigger works fine. But how do I recreate the Zip Code spreadsheet as a custom Territory object. The custom object has custom Fields - Zip Code(Text), Owner(Lookup(User)). Should this be included in the Accounts trigger or should I have a separate trigger for custom Territory object. I am not able to understand.

Comment: Please open a separate post for new questions. That sounds like you simply need to do a data load.